# Is there a pattern for "first best match" or predicate fallbacks in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

Is there a pattern for selecting the first element in an `Enumerable` that matches a condition or the next best element using another condition if the first condition is not met?

Say I have an `IEnumerable<Meal>` and I want to select the first `Meal` with a `MealType` that best matches my preference.

```cs
public enum MealType
{
    BurgerMeal,
    PizzaMeal,
    FriedChickenMeal,
}

public class Meal
{
    public MealType Type { get; set; }

    // extra details elided
}
```

If my order of preference from most preferred to least preferred is

```
 burger, pizza, chicken
```

then given `[ burger, chicken, pizza ]` I should select `burger`, given `[ chicken, pizza ]` I should select `pizza` and given `[ chicken ]` I should select `chicken`:

```
[ burger, chicken, pizza ] => burger   # since burger is the most preferred
[ chicken, pizza ]         => chicken
[ pizza ]                  => pizza
```

A less generic solution in iterative code might look like this. Unfortunately the inverted loops is not immediately clear. The meals should be the focus rather than the preferences.

```cs
public static Meal GetBestMealOrDefault(IEnumerable<Meal> meals, IEnumerable<MealType> preferences)
{
    foreach (var preference in preferences)
    {
        foreach (var meal in meals)
        {
            if (meal.Type == preference)
            {
                return meal;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I have considered something like `meals.OrderBy(meal => meal.type, new MealTypePreferenceComparer()).First()` where `MealTypePreferenceComparer : IComparer<MealType>` but it feels a bit heavy-handed.

The first match is important to the problem, `meals` already has an order that is based on other priorities.

Are there any out of the box algorithms (or ways of composing them) that can achieve this?

Comment: I'm confused by your requirements here. It seems like a simple sort and select first, as you have shown in the question. I don't understand what your issue is with that approach?

Comment: The term "first best match" confused me quite a bit, because I falsely assumed that the desired operation is singular. But you are actually searching for something like `.BestMatches(someLambda).First()`, or a variant `FirstBestMatch` that is further optimized to avoid caching all the best matches during the enumeration. It is complex operation in other words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can try *map* preferences to `int` (`0, 1, 2, 3...`), i.e. for
`burger, chicken, pizza` we will have

```
 map = {
   { burger,  0 },
   { chicken, 1 },
   { pizza,   2 },
 }
```

and then `OrderBy` by the computed integers.

**Code:**

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 public static Meal GetBestMealOrDefault(IEnumerable<Meal> meals, 
                                         IEnumerable<MealType> preferences) {
   if (null == meals)
     throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(meals));
   else if (null == preferences)
     throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(preferences));
   
   var map = preferences
     .Distinct() // to be on the safe side
     .Select((item, index) => new {item, index})
     .ToDictionary(pair => pair.item, pair.index);

   return meals
     .OrderBy(item => map.TryGetValue(item.Type, out int order) 
        ? order  
        : int.MaxValue)
     .FirstOrDefault(); 
 }
```

**Edit:** If you have *long* collections of `meals` and the most preferenced item is often within the collection you can *improve performance* (see Dialecticus's comment) by looping:

```
 public static Meal GetBestMealOrDefault(IEnumerable<Meal> meals, 
                                         IEnumerable<MealType> preferences) {
   if (null == meals)
     throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(meals));
   else if (null == preferences)
     throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(preferences));
   
   var map = preferences
     .Distinct() // to be on the safe side
     .Select((item, index) => new {item, index})
     .ToDictionary(pair => pair.item, pair.index);

   Meal result = default(Meal);
   int bestScore = int.MaxValue;

   foreach (Meal meal in meals) {
     int score = map.TryGetValue(meal.Type, out int order) 
        ? order  
        : int.MaxValue);

     if (default(Meal) == result || bestScore > score) {
       bestScore = score;
       result = meal;

       if (bestScore == 0) // the best meal found, no more looping
         break;
     }
   } 

   return result;
 }
```

Comment: `OrderBy` must loop through the whole collection, but once we find the first preferred item we can stop searching.

Comment: One `TakeWhile` before `OrderBy` should end the search if we've found the most preferred item.

Comment: Well, actually it has to be [`TakeUntil`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/TakeUntil.cs) instead of TakeWhile.

Comment: @Dialecticus: techinclally, yes, `TakeWhile` can improve the performance, but in case of really long `IEnumerable<Meal> meals`, I'd *get rid* of `OrderBy` (which reads the entire `meals` into memory, when, say `meals` is some kind of file or cursor) and check for the topmost preference.

Comment: Thanks, mapping the `MealType` to an `int` and then comparing on the `int` was the part I was missing. My data sets are quite small so ordering the whole thing is not an issue. My MVCE is more generic than I actually need so I can simplify some of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with some LINQ as shown here:

```
var meals = new List<Meal>();
// var selectedPreferences = new List<MealType>();

var bestMatch = meals
            // .Where(x => selectedPreferences
            // .Any(p => p == x.Type))
            .GroupBy(x => x.Type)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .FirstOrDefault();

if (bestMatch is null)
{
    // handle
}

// go ahead
```

and the sorting of the meals is not affected. Or just complete your querying of the meals with this:

```
    .GroupBy(x => x.Type)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

My actual problem was slightly less generic than my MVCE and I only have to deal with small datasets. [Dmitry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63916266/8778450) put me on the right track with a `MealType` to `int` mapper which saved me from writing a single use `IComparer<MealType>`.

My solution ended up being

```cs
// elided …

static int GetPriority(MealType type)
{
    return type switch
    {
        MealType.BurgerMeal => 0,
        MealType.PizzaMeal => 1,
        MealType.FriedChickenMeal => 2,
        _ => int.MaxValue,
    };
}

return meals
    .OrderBy(meal => meal.OtherCriteria)
    .ThenBy(meal => GetPriority(meal.Type))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```